# Copy / Paste from other workbooks

Tags: image, vba, excel, copy-paste

I wrote code to copy and paste to my workbook the used ranges from other workbooks. In my computer it works but when I send to anyone the paste process results in an error message:

> "This image cannot currently be displayed."

[image]

The currently version, I used xlPasteAll:

```
Workbooks(fl.Name).Worksheets(sheetindex).Range("A2:P" & Lastrow).Copy
Workbooks(fl.Name).Close
Worksheets(sheetindex).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(startrow,1),Cells(rangeCount,16)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

Comment: did yo try closing the source wb after copying the data?

Comment: I tried but did't paste to the target range

Comment: Are you sending as an outlook message attachment. If you are sending as an outlook message then outlook trust center settings should not have checked Checkbox related to Do'nt Download pictures automatically in HTML email messages at the receipients end.

Comment: i want copy only datas to range without images. The source workbook does't contains any image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this [KB-Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2597034). 
It describes an error which occurs with images from other workbooks while copying a sheet or range into an other workbook.

Had a similar problem - we copied a sheet with images into the target workbook. If you close the source workbook before you save and close the target workbook this error would occur. 
If you left the source workbook open and closed the target workbook, the image was shown correctly (Close source workbook afterwards and reopen the target workbook manually).

The KB-Article/Hoftix was able to fix our problem - it would also explain why it works on your Workstation and not somewhere else. (Different office patches...)

Comment: Similar problem. I set the registry and fixed my workstation but I cant do in all of ws.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the sheet after copy the values. use close command after pasting the values

```
  Sub test()

    Workbooks(fl.Name).Worksheets(sheetindex).Range("A2:P" & Lastrow).Copy
    Worksheets(sheetindex).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(startrow, 1), Cells(rangeCount, 16)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Workbooks(fl.Name).Close
 End Sub
```